# it's bad enough ( having to / to have to / to ) read

Tags: difference

Please clarify the difference between each option in the sentence below.

> I would never use "got decapitated" in a formal report unless I was
>   quoting a witness who said that, because it's bad enough **having to / to have to / to**
>   read these things to begin with, the last thing I want is to increase
>   the immediacy of the description for whomever the poor person having
>   to read it is (sometimes myself in the future) and possibly
>   vicariously traumatize them (even worse).

Comment: Is the paragraph grammatical? :( What's the source?

Comment: Hi :) The original one is "having to" but I am curious to know what will differ if I replace it with "to have to" or "to". http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22684/was-decapitated-or-got-decapitated

Comment: Yes, after your edit it makes some sense ;)

Comment: I think both *to*-infinitive and the *-ing* form work fine and have a similar meaning. So "It's bad enough having to read" and "It's bad enough to have to read" both seem to work, but having two *to*-infinitive might sound a little jarring (like those double *-ing*, e.g. *She was starting reading her book.*) Also, "bad enough reading" and "bad enough to read" are both possible, imo, but they have no "have to" connotation.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Thank you so much :) I am not sure if "having to" is the progressive form of "have to" (obligation or certainty)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think you've nailed it - post it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the clause,

> It's bad enough **having to read** these things.

This basically means the same as,

> It's bad enough **to have to read** these things.

Preparatory *it* is common with both an infinitive expression (*to have to read*) and an *-ing* form (*having to read*). (The *-ing* form is a little more informal.) So, you can use either form. It might be worth noting that saying *"to have to X"* might sound a little jarring, like those double *-ing*, e.g. *"She was starting reading her book."* Personally, I tend to rephrase *"to have to X"* to *"having to X"* myself, too.

It would be fine to write either of these,

> It's bad enough **to read** these things.
>   It's bad enough **reading** these things.

They would have a similar meaning to your original, but without the "have to" connotation.